# Is it possible to link graphviz elements to sphinx links?

Tags: python-sphinx, graphviz

I use [graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) in my [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) documentation and would like to reuse links automatically generated by the RestructuredText code.

> You may want to jump directly to the UPDATE 2 at the bottom for a
> summary (spoiler: does not work for me)

The output I get from

```
Hello
-----
Test of a graph

.. graphviz::

    digraph process {
           a [label="first", href="http://google.com"];
           b [label="second", href="#World"];
           a -> b;
        }

World
-----
Something else.
```

is correct, but despite the fact that the generated image is an `SVG`, `first`and `second` are not clickable:

[image]

**If I right click the embedded image and open it in a new tab, it has active links I can click on.** It looks like if embedding the image prevented the links from being active.

The elements of my `conf.py` relevant to graphviz:

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.graphviz'
]
graphviz_output_format = 'svg'
```

Is there something specific to set up in Sphinx to have this behaviour for embedded graphs?

## UPDATE

[bug report filed](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2175)

## UPDATE 2

I tried this with an [updated Sphinx](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/2176) (which pulls in changes related to graphviz). The results are:

- opening a new page does not work. I chose a non-HTTPS page (http://www.timeanddate.com/) instead of Google and I get the page embedded in an `IFRAME`:

[image]

- the result is consistent across browsers (Chrome 47, FF 43, IE Edge)

The summary is that the embedding functionality (thank you @xuhdev for the work) is, at least for me, non functional.

Comment: What do you mean the links are not present?

Comment: I mean that neither `first` nor `second` are clickable on the embedded version, while they are in the standalone.

Comment: I tested your example---it works for me...

Comment: Perhaps you can post a little more of your `conf.py`?

Comment: Updated. I also clarified the question following your initial comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the problem, which I consider it a bug. The graphviz extension inserts svg images inside `<img>`, which makes the svg files non-interactive. I've [made a pull request](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/2176) to fix the issue by replacing the img tag with object. You can workaround at this moment by using my branch:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/xuhdev/sphinx@graphviz-interactive-svg
```

An alternative solution which add an option to inline the svg files is also [available](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/2014).

Also you need to update your graphviz file with `target`:

```
digraph process {
       a [label="first", href="http://google.com", target="_top"];
       b [label="second", href="#World"];
       a -> b;
    }
```

You can view possible targets [here](http://apike.ca/prog_svg_web_links.html).

Comment: Thank you! I filed a bug in github in the meantime (https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2175), you may want to link to it or I can remove it, whatever practical.

Comment: I tried your code, the links are added (and they point to the right URL) but nothing happens when they are clicked. If I right-click on the link (say, `first` in my example) and choose to open in a different tab - it works (I get `google.com`).

Comment: Specifically, there is no action on Chrome when clicking on the link ; in Firefox the image dissapears (leaving a blank).

Comment: Unfortunately this did not change the behaviour (same as described, for both Chrome and FF)

Comment: @WoJ That's a little strange, as it works perfectly for me on FF. Can you make sure you have successfully rebuilt the html files after saving the RST file? Did you clicked on "first" ("second" won't work)?

Comment: Yes, I checked by changing the labels (to be extra sure) and with the stable version of Sphinx (with your pull). I updated (UPDATE 2) my post with the results.

Comment: @WoJ Thanks for the update. Can you generate a small reproduceable code and upload it somewhere (with everything including `conf.py`), and the generated html files? I would like to inspect the issue more deeply.